# python Get the unique values from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to get the unique values from my dictionary.

Input:

```
{320: [167], 316: [0], 319: [167], 401: [167], 319: [168], 380: [167], 265: [166]}
```

Desired Output:

```
[167,0,168,166]
```

My code :

```
unique_values = sorted(set(pff_dict.itervalues()))
```

But I'm getting this error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you are mapping to single-item lists as values, but you can use a list comprehension to extract the elements.

```
foobar = {320: [167], 316: [0], 319: [167], 401: [167], 319: [168], 380: [167], 265: [166]}
print list(set([x[0] for x in foobar.values()]))
```

If you start out by mapping directly to values though, the code can be much simpler.

```
foobar = {320: 167, 316: 0, 319: 167, 401: 167, 319: 168, 380: 167, 265: 166}
print list(set(foobar.values()))
```

Answer (score 4):

Lists do not qualify as candidate set content because they are *unhashable*.

You can merge the items into one container using [`itertoos.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) before calling `set`:

```
from itertools import chain

unique_values = sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(pff_dict.itervalues())))
```

Note that using `itertools` does not violate your choice of `dict.itervalues` over `dict.values` as the unwrapping/chaining is done *lazily*.

Comment: The name given to the dict is pure gold.

Answer (score 0):

`set` expect an elements not list of list, So you have to create a list of elements using `list comprehension`

```
In [34]: sorted(set([i[0] for i in d.values()]))
Out[34]: [0, 166, 167, 168]
```