# Python script to monitor a directory triggers twice when a file is updated. Why?

Tags: python, readdirectorychangesw

Short version:
A Python script I've written/adapted to monitor a directory for changes triggers twice when a file is modified.  Why?

Long version:

I'm writing some Python code to monitor a directory and its subdirectories for changes.

I'm starting with the example found in the "Use the ReadDirectoryChanges API" section of http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

(For corporate IT reasons, using the Python Watchdog package isn't an option for me.)

Cutting-and-pasting from the example there:

```
import os

import win32file
import win32con

ACTIONS = {
  1 : "Created",
  2 : "Deleted",
  3 : "Updated",
  4 : "Renamed from something",
  5 : "Renamed to something"
}
# Thanks to Claudio Grondi for the correct set of numbers
FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

path_to_watch = "."
hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
  path_to_watch,
  FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
  win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
  None,
  win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
  win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
  None
)
while 1:
  #
  # ReadDirectoryChangesW takes a previously-created
  # handle to a directory, a buffer size for results,
  # a flag to indicate whether to watch subtrees and
  # a filter of what changes to notify.
  #
  # NB Tim Juchcinski reports that he needed to up
  # the buffer size to be sure of picking up all
  # events when a large number of files were
  # deleted at once.
  #
  results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
    hDir,
    1024,
    True,
    win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
     win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
    None,
    None
  )
  for action, file in results:
    full_filename = os.path.join (path_to_watch, file)
    print full_filename, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown")
```

In general, this example is working fine and doing what I want.  In particular, it works fine when a file is created.  However, when a file is edited / modified / updated, the print statement at the end (which is standing in for the action I really want to do) triggers twice.

Why does this happen?  And how can prevent it, or at least work around it?  The best idea I've had is a flag that is True the first time and False the second time.  However, that feels like a kludge.

On a possibly related issue, where can I find documentation on the win32con package and the Microsoft ReadDirectoryChanges API?  I've done some Googling but haven't found anything I consider useful.

Oh, yes - I'm running Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

EDIT:
OK, it looks like what I'm seeing may be inherent in ReadDirectoryChangesW().  I discovered this StackOverflow thread which appears to be basically the same problem, except the original poster is using C++, not Python. [C++ WinApi: ReadDirectoryChangesW() Receiving Double Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036449/c-winapi-readdirectorychangesw-receiving-double-notifications)

Comment: You're watching for size change and last write change. When editing a file, those two parameters might change alltogether. Thereby it fires twice. Try to remove the size watcher if you aren't working on files opened by other programs.

Comment: Ah.  Duh.  I was thinking I'd get one response if any of the conditions were true but I'm sure you're correct - I'm getting one response for EVERY condition that's true.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you could do (if you don't care what action has triggered) is check wether results has more than one entry and if it is the case check if the same file appear twice. Or simply get unique dictionnary values as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917131/python-get-the-unique-values-from-a-dictionary

Comment: OK, this may be more complicated than we thought.  I've commented out both the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE and FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES lines.  However, the print statement is still triggering twice.  Oddly, the "results" variable only lists a single item: [(3, 'New Text Document.txt']

Comment: What are the actions that are being triggered? And is this the same file?

Comment: I updated my comment - accidentally hit "Enter".  Does my updated commend answer your question?  And it's the same file - I'm just editing the existing line or adding a new line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183190/discussion-between-mael-pedretti-and-bobinbaltimore).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't go to chat.  Corporate IT again.

Comment: This is really weird. I am not sure why this would happen. Is there a way to "confirm" that you have received the notification?
I don't know how the function `ReadDirectoryChangesW` but maybe you're going too fast over this function and this is what triggers the watcher twice.
Try adding a delay after the print function (maybe 500ms to start with) and check if you still have your function triggered twice

Comment: I've added time.sleep(1) but I'm still getting double prints.  In addition to the sleep, I've commented out all the checks except FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE and FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I won't be able to help you more for the moment. I really don't know why this triggers twice as it shouldn't.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for the help and suggestions you've given so far.

Answer (score 2):

i don't have python 2.7 installed so i cannot test this myself by looking at this part

```
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | #this will change when someone writes or deletes to the file
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |#this will change when someone modifies the file
 win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
```

see how both conditions could be triggered by the same action? it's possible this is what is triggering your behaviour, try removing one of the two

**Edit to clarify comments below:**

in order to get an idea of the behaviour for each type of change try this:

```
results = {}
results['FName_Change'] = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                        hDir,
                        1024,
                        True,
                        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
                        None,
                        None
                      )
results['DName_Change'] = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                        hDir,
                        1024,
                        True,
                         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME, 
                        None,
                        None
                        )
  results['Attributes_Change'] = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                        hDir,
                        1024,
                        True,
                         win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES, 
                        None,
                        None
```

by manipulating this data structure you should be able to extract behaviour type information from the changes

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure you're correct.  As I commented above, I was thinking I'd get one response if any condition was true but I'm getting one response for every condition that's true.

Comment: The only problem I can think about here is the following:
He's watching a log file opened by another process. The file will keep growing but I am not sure that the last write will change as the file remains open.

Comment: For my use case, that's not an issue.  I'm watching for data files created by another program, not log files updated by another program.  Once the file is created, I want to process it.  Ditto if the file is updated, which would typically be done manually to correct a data entry issue.

Comment: what you could do is split `results` with an individual `win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW()` call for each of the items/notification types and then store them sepparately, that way you can get a better idea of what changes are actually being made

Comment: "results" has only a single entry: [(3, 'New Text Document.txt'].  There's nothing to split.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: made a change to the answer to answer the above

Comment: Thanks - good idea!  I need to go to a meeting and do some other things but I'll give your idea a try as soon as I have the chance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that your suggestion won't work it terms of figuring out what's going on.  From what I can tell, ReadDirectoryChangesW() just sits there waiting for the specified change to occur.  Program execution doesn't proceed until the specified change is seen.  For example, editing the contents of a file and the save-quitting the editor doesn't trigger any action because the program is still waiting to see an attribute change.  However, it appears that creating a file triggers both the FName_Change and DName_Change checks, which I guess makes sense, once I thought about it.

Comment: Hmm yeah, in that case you'll need parallel scripts to do that

Comment: It looks like what I'm seeing may be inherent in ReadDirectoryChangesW().  I discovered a StackOverflow post where the original poster appears to be having the same problem as me, only he's using C++, not Python.  I've updated my original post with this information.